# How literate were Kamchadal people?

Tags: russia, language, kamchatka

Kamchatka was settled by Russians starting around 1700. I get the impression that by 1800 most people in Kamchatka had mixed heritages. According to UNESCO, [Itelmen languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itelmen_language) were already extinct. While those European Russians in towns were probably speaking a more formal Russian, a regional form of the language was spoken in the Kamchadal villages.

Krasheninnikov and Gromov both mentioned schools in the 1740s and 1750s, presumably primary schools. However, Langsdorff mentioned around 1805 that one Russian village school was for "the sons of soldiers only, never the Kamschadales".

Considering that the Russian language already dominated in Kamchatka by 1800, how literate were Kamchadal people?

Comment: What does it do with the language? Most Russians from rural areas were illiterate even at the beginning of 20th century.